# Mapeo ambiguo, no se puede asignar el método

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

Dentro de mi controlador de java `CredentialController.java` tengo lo siguiente:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/application_oauth2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

El error presente en consola es:

> ```
> There is already 'credentialController' bean method
> ```

Comment: Puedes mostrar como tienes tu controlador CredentialController.java  probablemente falte @Controller

Comment: @SoftMolina mi controlador está así:        
    
             
   "  arrobaRestController
public class CredentialController 
{
 arrobaAutowired
 private CredentialDAO credentialDAO;
 

 arrobaOverride
 public void finalize() throws Throwable {
 } 
 arrobaAutowired
 private CredentialDAO credentialDAO2;
 "

Le he puesto la palabra arroba en reemplazo del signo @

Comment: @RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/credentialController") public class CredentialController {}      si usas servicios rest debería ser así

Answer (score 0):

No parece que sea problema con un mapeo ambiguo, cuando eso ocurre la excepción mostrada es algo así:

```
Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'credentialController' bean method
```

Más bien parece un problema de tener registrado más de una vez ese bean. ¿Es posible que, además de etiquetarlo como `@RestController`, lo tengas también definido mediante `XML`?

Por otra parte, para añadir nuevo código, puedes editar la pregunta y añadirlo allí en lugar de en los comentarios, quedará mucho más claro.